# Parse Server Linking Existing User with Facebook in Android Gives No Result

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-login, parse-server

I need help about an issue that I am looking for hours and still not solved.

I am trying to use the linking current user with facebook property of parse server using android. I am also using the singin with facebook property, but have no problems there. However, when I use the linking property with the code below, the facebook enter username password dialog opens. Then I give permission to read the listed data from facebook and click ok. When it turns back to my app, nothing happens and I see the lines below in the log.

As the emulator I use Nexus 6 API 23 Android 6.0 x86

My code is:

```
System.out.println("I am here 1");

                List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");

                System.out.println("I am here 2");

                if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {

                    System.out.println("I am here 3");
                    ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(), this, permissions, new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException ex) {
                            System.out.println("I am here 4");
                            if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
                                Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");

                            }

                            else {

                                Log.e("MyLast", "unexpected error of mine", ex);


                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
```

In the log I see:

```
06-16 10:57:40.049 11878-11878/com.my_last.mylast W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 11878
06-16 10:57:40.084 11878-11987/com.my_last.mylast E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9cbad8b0
06-16 10:57:40.305 11878-11987/com.my_last.mylast E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40982e0
```

In the println lines, I see until "I am here 3". before the log lines above.

Any help would be great, I looked everywhere but could not found any reasons. I use the code inside a fragment, and I also tried using `getActivity()` rather than `this`, but same result.